# WPF: switching UserControls depending on corresponding ViewModels (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'll try to simplify the task I'm working on by imagining this example:

Let's suppose that we have the following hierarchy of model classes:

```
Animal
   Lion
   Snake
   Bird
```

...corresponding ViewModels:

```
AnimalCollectionViewModel
   AnimalViewModel
      LionViewModel
      SnakeViewModel
      BirdViewModel
```

... and corresponding views:

```
AnimalCollectionView
   LionView
   SnakeView
   BirdView
```

It's supposed that AnimalCollection contains a list filled with objects of different types of animals and below the list it has a property grid for setting the properties of a selected animal. Obviously the property grids will have different properties and should change when the type of a selected item changes.

The question is: How to implement switching of the property grids in WPF according to the MVVM pattern? Using what mechanism?

Currently I have an abstract enum property in the base ViewModel (AnimalViewModel.PropertyGridType = {Lion, Snake, Bird}) which the derived classes implement by returning corresponding values. And the AnimalCollectionView changes the property grid user controls depending on the value of this property. Something like this:

...

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PropertyGridStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PropertyGridType}" Value="Lion">
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <view:LionPropertyGridView />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PropertyGridType}" Value="Snake">
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <view:SnakePropertyGridView />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource PropertyGridStyle}" />
```

...

But I'm not sure whether it is the right approach. (At least I don't like introducing the auxiliary enum property. Is it possible to deduce the necessary user control based on a ViewModel type?)
Can anybody advise other options?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: as long as the logic of your view is separated from the view and you use databinding, you are comfortably in mvvm land. One of the major, major benefits of doing this is testability, so start with a use case and some tests. Then you can apply different OOP and wpf techniques as you like. Cheers

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Is it possible to deduce the necessary user control based on a ViewModel type?

You mean, like this?

```
<Window.Resources>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LionViewModel}">
      <v:LionView />
   </DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SnakeViewModel}">
      <v:SnakeView />
   </DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BirdViewModel}">
      <v:BirdView/>
   </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

See "Applying a View to a View Model" in [Josh Smith's article on MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090016).

**Edit:**

Here's a trivial example of type-based template selection that you can paste into Kaxaml to prove to yourself that it really works:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <Page.Resources>
    <sys:String x:Key="string">this is a string</sys:String>
    <sys:Int32 x:Key="int32">1234</sys:Int32>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
      <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
      <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" Text="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Page.Resources>
  <StackPanel>  
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource string}}"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource int32}}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: I'm almost sure this is exactly what I meant :))
Thank you, Robert

Comment: Type-based template selection is my single favorite feature of WPF.  Understanding all of its implications is what moved me into the identifying-with-my-torturers phase of the WPF learning curve.

Comment: Thank you again, Robert. One more question: Does applying these data templates mean that they should be used in collection-like controls (like ListBox-es)? Can they be applied for instance to UserControls for displaying a single data item?

Comment: You can use them in either items controls or content controls.  For instance, `<ContentControl Content="{Binding X}"/>` creates a `ContentPresenter` that contains whatever data template matches `X`'s type, just as `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding X}"/>` creates a panel full of `ItemsPresenters`.  (Generally, anything with an `ItemsSource` property is an items control; anything with a `Content` property is a content control.)`

Comment: ... but I think I'm missing something because it doesn't work:
I defined DataTemplates as you had wrote in your main answer, and when I'm using the ContentControl like this:

<ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=lstAnimals, Path=SelectedItem}" />

It just shows the ViewModel type name (PropertyGrid.ViewModels.SnakeViewModel)

Comment: Well, I can't tell you what you're doing wrong without more information, but I can tell you that it should work - check the edit I made to my comment for a quick test case that you can paste into Kaxaml.

Comment: Thank you again, Robert. Could you, please, tell me how I can display not to objects defined statically but to an object selected in another list control. For instance, instead of <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource string}}"/> I want to get somthing like this <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={XXX ElementName=lstAnimals,Path=SelectedItem}}"/>? (I tried various combinations with no luck so far ((

Comment: You're on the right track.  In practice, you'll often create a `SelectedItem` property in the collection view model - if, for instance, you're implementing commands - and bind both the selected item in the list box and the content of the content control to that property.  To bind directly to a control, use `{Binding ElementName=foo, Path=SelectedItem}`.  If that isn't working, put some literal content in the control and make sure it's visible - I've spent a lot of time troubleshooting perfectly-functioning bindings when the real problem was one of layout.

Comment: Robert, thank you for your patience - with your help I finally got what I wanted.

Comment: You're more than welcome.  I've grown very enthusiastic about WPF, but it was as hard to learn as anything I've picked up in my 30+ years as a professional software developer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) for that. The method of choosing the right template is up to you. You can use enums or test for class type if you wish.

Comment: Thank you, Goran, I'll take a look at it