# One WPF Window that displays different DataGrid's based on Menu selection?

Tags: mvvm, datagrid, datasource

I want to display different `DataSource` (SQL) queries in one 'DataGrid' based on `Menu` selections. Am I barking up the wrong tree by looking at `UserControl`'s? How would this be implemented?

**Edit:**
I've finally found [Changing user control on list selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007729/changing-user-control-on-list-selection) which seems to answer my question pretty well, or at least modifies my question a little. So one `Menu` is to list all "Parts" available. The other `Menu` has `MenuItems` that correspond to locations and ultimately the inventory of said Parts at each location. Currently I am using a Click handler for each `MenuItem` and create a new instance of a specific `UserControl` for Parts and each location.

```
private void menuParts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dgRoot.Children.Clear();
        UserControl control = new ucParts();
        this.dgRoot.Children.Add(control);
        this.Title = "Inventory Manager - Parts";
    }
```

and

```
private void menuSG1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dgRoot.Children.Clear();
        UserControl control = new ucSG1();
        this.dgRoot.Children.Add(control);
        this.Title = "Inventory Manager - SG1";
    }
```

My question now is, can I create a reusable UserControl template that the Click handler can feed the location name to? The data is displayed, formatted, used, etc the same way, it's ultimately just the underlying DataSource query that is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seemingly CAN do this. Just create the generic usercontrol `Grid` in my case.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="menuMain" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
        <MenuItem Header="Parts">
            <MenuItem Name="menuParts" Header="Parts" Click="menuParts_Click"/>
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Name="addPart" Header="Add Part" Click="addPart_Click" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Inventory">
            <MenuItem Name="menuBrady" Header="Brady" Click="menuBrady_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="menuCO" Header="Community" Click="menuCO_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="menuPoly" Header="Poly" Click="menuPoly_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="menuSG1" Header="SG1" Click="menuSG1_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="menuWS" Header="West Shore" Click="menuWS_Click"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Grid Name="dgRoot" />
</DockPanel>
```

Then as shown in my `Click` handlers above, use them!